Highest 2 Dice of 3D6 with reroll if total is under 8
Trying to add the reroll function to
output [highest 2 of 3d6]

If the total of the original roll (after removing lowest) is under 8.

Can you clarify what exactly gets rerolled when? Is it one die, or all three? Is it once, or for as long as the total keeps coming up below 8?

ROLL: [highest 2 of 3d6]
 
function: reroll A:s under B:n {
  if A < B {
     result: ROLL
   } 
   result: A
 }

 output [reroll ROLL under 8]

This makes use of the function property that the function will be invoked for all possible sums that can be made by rolling those dice and keeping the highest. So the if clause is invoked in sequence for all possible results of the original roll, and in each case, there is only one value for that result, which is compared to your treshold, and if it is under, a reroll is returned (new roll of the same dice) else the rolled number is returned. The result of a function that is invoked for a sequence or die then will be a new die.
Here is the results for your values


If you want to handle unlimited rerolls rather than just one, replace result: ROLL with result: d{}, which basically assigns a zero probability to that outcome.

@Blckknght Yes, that is a cool trick. Ilmari and HighDiceRoller are just the best when it comes to these kind of questions.

To give credit where it's due, I learned that trick from Carcer.

Using the generic helper function from this answer I wrote earlier:
function: ROLL:n replace FILTER:s with REROLL:d {
  if ROLL = FILTER { result: REROLL }
  result: ROLL
}

we can solve your task with:
output [[highest 2 of 3d6] replace {0..7} with [highest 2 of 3d6]]

or, using a variable to avoid repetition:
ROLL: [highest 2 of 3d6]
output [ROLL replace {0..7} with ROLL]

The output looks the same in both cases, as expected:


Ps. The code above assumes that you want to reroll only once, and take whatever result you get from the reroll even if it's still less than 8.
If you instead want to keep rerolling until you roll 8 or more, a useful AnyDice trick is to replace the rerolled results with the "empty die" d{}. This is a special AnyDice value that, when returned from a function, basically tells AnyDice to pretend that the roll that produced that outcome never happened.  So code like this:
output [[highest 2 of 3d6] replace {0..7} with d{}]

effectively calculates the probability distribution of rolling 3d6 and taking the sum of the highest two dice under the assumption that the sum will always be at least 8.  Which is equivalent to rerolling any results below 8 repeatedly until you do roll at least 8.
The output in this case looks fairly similar to that shown above, except that the chance of rolling under 8 twice is eliminated and the lowest possible result is indeed 8:


Great answer. This empty dice trick should really be added to the anydice documentation imo. I work as a software developer, but it still took me over an hour to figure how to make a repeated reroll function for the first time.
